# Alliteration on text

Tags: string-manipulation

I want to create a list of pairs of successive alliterating words, using Select.
I have this so far

```
 Partition[TextWords@[insert text here], 2, 1],
 StringTake[#, 1] == StringTake[#, 2] &
 ]
```

but it's not working, I know the StringTake is wrong but I'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: Define what you mean by alliteration and show some examples of typical input and the associated expected output.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2894483).

Answer (score 2):

Using @MichaelE2's dataset and looking up the [phonetic onset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable#Onset) of each word:

```
data = TextWords@ExampleData@{"Text", "TheRaven"};

onset[s_String] := Module[{ph},
  ph = WordData[ToLowerCase[s], "PhoneticForm"];
  If[MissingQ[ph], "",
    StringTake[StringDelete[ph, "ˈ" | "ˌ"], UpTo[1]]]]

SequenceCases[data, {a_, b_} /; 
  onset[a] == onset[b] != "" &&
  ToLowerCase[a] != ToLowerCase[b], 
  Overlaps -> All] // DeleteDuplicates

(* {{"upon", "a"}, {"nodded", "nearly"}, {"nearly", "napping"},
    {"lost", "Lenore"}, {"it", "is"}, {"Sir", "said"},
    {"door", "Darkness"}, {"Doubting", "dreaming"},
    {"dreaming", "dreams"}, {"before", "But"},
    {"whispered", "word"}, {"and", "an"},
    {"chamber", "turning"}, {"again", "a"},
    {"lattice", "Let"}, {"when", "with"}, {"Then", "this"},
    {"bird", "beguiling"}, {"Though", "thy"},
    {"Ghastly", "grim"}, {"one", "word"}, {"hopes", "have"},
    {"Then", "the"}, {"broken", "by"}, {"is", "its"},
    {"Followed", "fast"}, {"followed", "faster"},
    {"burden", "bore"}, {"his", "Hope"},
    {"Never", "nevermore"}, {"sad", "soul"},
    {"smiling", "Straight"}, {"ghastly", "gaunt"},
    {"that", "the"}, {"velvet", "violet"}, {"She", "shall"},
    {"censer", "Swung"}, {"he", "hath"}, {"tempest", "tossed"},
    {"Horror", "haunted"}, {"implore", "Is"}, {"form", "from"},
    {"sitting", "still"}} *)
```

Some triple alliterations:

```
SequenceCases[data, {a_, b_, c_} /;
  onset[a] == onset[b] == onset[c] != "",
  Overlaps -> All] // DeleteDuplicates

(* {{"nodded", "nearly", "napping"},
    {"Doubting", "dreaming", "dreams"}} *)
```

There are quite a few differences coming from phonetic matching because [English spelling is very irregular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghoti):

- *upon* (əpˈɒn) matches *a* (ə)
- *chamber* (tʃˈeɪmbɝ) matches *turning* (tˈɝnɪŋ)
- *one* (wˈʌn) matches *word* (wˈɝd)
- *implore* (ˌɪmplˈɔr) matches *is* (ˈɪz) if we allow primary/secondary syllable alliterations
- *scarce* (skˈɛrs) does not match *sure* (ʃˈʊr)

etc.

Note, however, that only about 20% of the words in `WordData[]` have a known `PhoneticForm`. All others will fail and not give alliteration possibilities here.

Answer (score 1):

I posted the answer on community.Wolfram.com, but the answer was published by an error of unknwon origin under the name of a moderator.

```
 text = "Simply speaking: group word list into subsets with same first 
    character, eventually restricted to the CharacterRange, and select 
    from the Gather list the subset with count > 1";

wordList = TextWords[text];  

allitteralQ[a_ , b_ ] :=SameQ @@ ((StringTake[#, 1] & ) /@ (ToLowerCase /@ {a, b}))

Select[Union /@ Gather[wordList, (allitteralQ[#1, #2] &)], (Length[#] > 1 &)]
```

All in One

```
Select[Union /@ Gather[TextWords[text],
Function[{a,b},  
SameQ @@ ((StringTake[#, 1] & ) /@ (ToLowerCase /@ {a, b})) ]],
(Length[#] > 1 &)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because I miss Mr.Wizard's love of `SparseArray` methods (I'm pretty sure I learned this idea from one of their answers, though it's not nearly neat enough, to use alliteration):

```
data = TextWords@ ExampleData@ {"Text", "TheRaven"};
pos = SparseArray[
    1 - Unitize@ Differences@ Flatten@ 
      ToCharacterCode@ ToLowerCase@ StringTake[data, 1]
  ]["AdjacencyLists"];
Transpose@{data[[pos]], data[[1 + pos]]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For this poem, I'd recommend deleting stopwords, but beauty is in the eye, etc.

```
data = DeleteStopwords@TextWords@ExampleData[{"Text", "TheRaven"}];
pos = SparseArray[
    1 - Unitize@ Differences@ Flatten@ 
      ToCharacterCode@ ToLowerCase@ StringTake[data, 1]
  ]["AdjacencyLists"];
Transpose@{data[[pos]], data[[1 + pos]]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

If your sample text is assigned to the symbol `text`, then you could do this:

```
Select[Partition[TextWords[text], 2, 1], Apply[SameQ, ToLowerCase[StringPart[#, 1]]] &]
```

Of course, this is a simplistic interpretation of alliteration. Any given letter might actually be pronounced differently in different words. The function passed as the second argument to the `Select` would need to be adjusted if a more sophisticated analysis was desired.

Answer (score 1):

Using Michael E2's input data:

```
data = DeleteStopwords @ ToLowerCase @ TextWords @ ExampleData @ 
  {"Text", "TheRaven"};

Union @ Select[Length @ # >= 2 &] @ SplitBy[data, StringTake[#, 1] &]

Multicolumn[%, 4]
```

[image]